# How do I have IMAP delete Email inbox item when deleting on the server?

Tags: sync, email, imap

If I have an email in my Android Email inbox and I delete it on the server inbox, it will not delete from my phone.  If I delete it on the phone, it will delete it on the server.  I originally set it up this way but can't remember how and now would like to change it.  I can't find the settings to do so.